# ERROR 29040. HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, intellij-idea, pgadmin4

Подскажите, у меня не получается запустить приложение в IntelliJ IDEA. Ошибка ERROR 29040. HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. Я так понимаю, что не получается подключиться к базе данных. Захожу во вкладку database. Там сервер pgAdmin с базой данных. Подскажите, как перенести эту бд на свой сервер? В папке с проектом не нашёл sql файла. В папке проекта есть папка "database". В этой папке  ещё 1 папка "Shop.Fk8nAA" и  файл Shop.Fk8nAA.meta. В папке "Shop.Fk8nAA" находится папка "schema". В папке "schema" лежат 3 файла: information_schema.FNRwLQ.meta, pg_catalog.0S1ZNQ.meta, public.abK9xQ.meta. При "восстановлении" pgAdmin4 не видит .meta(